# How to generate all multipartite graphs in a combinatorial way?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, combinations

I have $n$ sets which contain $k_1$, $k_2$, ..., $k_n$ nodes. I would like to construct all the possible undirected $n$-partite graphs by establishing links among the nodes of these sets in all possible way? It would also be important for me how many such graphs there are. Could you give a combinatorial formula including $k_1$, $k_2$, ..., $k_n$ for that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the sets $S_1$, $S_2$, $\dots,$ $S_n$ be fixed sets with $k_1, k_2, \dots, k_n$ vertices.

IF we want to ensure that each $S_i$ is a partite set (with no edges inside it), then we can only add edges between partite sets.
If $S_i$ and $S_j$ are two of these sets, then there are $k_i \times k_j$ possible edges between them (each vertex of $S_i$, of which there are $k_i$, may have $k_j$ possible neighbors).

What we will do is add up all the possible edges by considering all possible pairings of sets $S_i$ and $S_j$.
So the total number of possible edges in this graph, $|E_{max}|$, is given by the sum:

$$
|E_{max}| = \sum \left\{k_i \times k_j : i < j \text{ and } i,j \in \{1,2,\dots,n\}  \right\}
$$

Let $u$ and $v$ be two vertices in different partite sets $S_i$ and $S_j$. Now in any given graph we want to consider, there are two opions: either the graph has the edge $uv$, or it doesn't.
So the total number of possible edge combinations is $2^{|E_{max}|}$.

Note: We are assuming a fixed vertex set here, and we are counting graphs that have different labels, but are isomorphic, as different.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Brandon! Can I ask whether you supposed undirected edges only? My multipartite graphs are undirected (which is not mentioned in the question, sorry - now corrected).

Comment: Happy to help ^^ 
Yes, the edges are undirected.

Comment: Thank you again. Let me allow one more (the last) question: is there a way to restrict the number of multipartite graphs by allowing only $d_\mathrm{max}$ degrees for all the edges?

Comment: In theory probably, but at first glance that seems like a much harder and more involved question. I don't have any good ideas about how you'd approach it.